# how to fetching app details like app logo, app name using url in php

Tags: php

i have URL of google play store and iTunes store and URL like this :
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/phonto-text-on-photos/id438429273?mt=8 
and
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ppl.cocos2dx.ranchrun&hl=en
like this 
so i want to fetch app logo, app name using that url and application type whether ios app or android app
so there is any code for this question in php.

$image_step = explode( '' , $content );
                        $second_step = explode("" , $image_step[1] );

using above code i can fetch only android app logo but its name cant fetch so give any solutions

Comment: There's plenty of code for it! And it's freely available all inside of you! All you need to do is write it.

Answer (score 1):

For iTunes, check out the [api page](http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html) and for tutorial visit [here](http://www.phponwebsites.com/2015/03/get-app-details-from-apple-itunes-using-php.html).

For Android, there is no official api, but you can find many unofficial and open source api's. One such api is [Google-Play-Store-API](https://github.com/thetutlage/Google-Play-Store-API)

Comment: is there possible to store image value in database?